# Java GUI, JFrame and Action Listeners

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

bellow is my code :).
i'm currently making a pizza delivery from in Java GUI i'm new to GUI.
I don't want too much help, but the goal is to create a program that every time i select and option or deselect it updates the order down the bottom and prompts the user when they miss something.
Currently i'm in the early stages and experiencing real trouble getting my containers onto my JFrame as well as getting it looking nice with a boarder (My container is no longer appearing in the jframe after some tinkering and my boarders are giving errors).
I also don't understand why my Else statements are being asked to be deleted if anyone could explain why in detail that'd be tremendous help i've used google and some study notes and it's just making my head spin.

```
   package com.test;

   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;

   public class PizzaGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        private JLabel lblTitle;
        private JLabel lblOrder;
        private JLabel lblSize;
        private JLabel lblToppings;
        private JLabel lblDelivery;
        private JLabel lblCustomer;
        private JCheckBox chkSmall;
        private JCheckBox chkMedium;
        private JCheckBox chkLarge;
        private JCheckBox chkYes;
        private JCheckBox chkNo;
        private JRadioButton radHam;
        private JRadioButton radPrawns;
        private JRadioButton radSalami;
        private JRadioButton radMushrooms;
        private JRadioButton radOlives;
        private JRadioButton radCapsicum;
        private JRadioButton radPineapple;
        private JTextField Name;
        private JTextField Phoneno;
        private JTextField Address;
        private double p = 0.0;

        ButtonGroup btgHtopping = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup btgltopping = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup btgSize = new ButtonGroup();
        ButtonGroup btgYesno = new ButtonGroup();

       Container size = getContentPane();
       Container ToppingH = getContentPane();
       Container ToppingL = getContentPane();
       Container Cust = getContentPane();


        size.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Please select one size"));
        ToppingH.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Please select all addittional toppings $1.50"));
        ToppingL.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Please select all addittional toppings $0.50"));
        Cust.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Customer Details"));

        public PizzaGUI()
        {

            radHam = new JRadioButton("Ham");
            radPrawns = new JRadioButton("Prawns");
            radSalami = new JRadioButton("Salami");
            radMushrooms = new JRadioButton("Mushrooms");
            radOlives = new JRadioButton("Olives");
            radCapsicum = new JRadioButton("Capsicum");
            radPineapple = new JRadioButton("Pineapple");
            chkNo = new JCheckBox("No");
            chkYes = new JCheckBox("Yes");
            chkLarge = new JCheckBox("Large");
            chkMedium = new JCheckBox("Medium");
            chkSmall = new JCheckBox("Small");
            lblTitle = new JLabel("Pizza Order Form");
            lblOrder = new JLabel(p + "");
            lblSize = new JLabel("Please select one size");
            lblToppings = new JLabel("Please select all addition toppings");
            lblDelivery = new JLabel("Delivery, Yes or No please choose $1.00 extra");
            lblCustomer = new JLabel("Customer Contact Details");
            Name = new JTextField(20);
            Phoneno = new JTextField(10);
            Address = new JTextField(50);

            btgHtopping.add(radHam);
            btgHtopping.add(radPrawns);
            btgHtopping.add(radSalami);
            btgltopping.add(radMushrooms);
            btgltopping.add(radOlives);
            btgltopping.add(radCapsicum);
            btgltopping.add(radPineapple);
            btgYesno.add(chkYes);
            btgYesno.add(chkNo);
            btgSize.add(chkLarge);
            btgSize.add(chkMedium);
            btgSize.add(chkSmall);

            size.add(lblTitle);
            size.add(lblSize);
            size.add(chkYes);
            size.add(chkNo);
            ToppingH.add(lblToppings);
            ToppingH.add(radHam);
            ToppingH.add(radSalami);
            ToppingH.add(radPrawns);
            ToppingL.add(radMushrooms);
            ToppingL.add(radOlives);
            ToppingL.add(radCapsicum);
            ToppingL.add(radPineapple);
            Cust.add(lblDelivery);
            Cust.add(lblCustomer);
            Cust.add(chkYes);
            Cust.add(chkNo);
            Cust.add(Name);
            Cust.add(Phoneno);
            Cust.add(Address);

            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            radHam.addActionListener(this);
            radPrawns.addActionListener(this);
            radSalami.addActionListener(this);
            radMushrooms.addActionListener(this);
            radOlives.addActionListener(this);
            radCapsicum.addActionListener(this);
            radPineapple.addActionListener(this);
            chkNo.addActionListener(this);
            chkYes.addActionListener(this);
            chkLarge.addActionListener(this);
            chkSmall.addActionListener(this);
            chkMedium.addActionListener(this);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionListener e)
        {

           String order="";
    if (chkLarge.isSelected()) {
        p = 8.00;
        order = "Large";

    }
    else if (chkMedium.isSelected()) {
        p = 6.00;
        order = "Medium";
    }

    else if (chkSmall.isSelected()) {
        p = 8.00;
        order = "Large";
    }

    if (radHam.isSelected()) {
        p += 1.50;
        order += "Ham";
    }else   {
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";  
    }

    if (radPrawns.isSelected()) {
        p += 1.50;
        order += "Prawns";
    } else  {
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";
    }

    if (radSalami.isSelected())   {
        p += 1.50;
        order += "Salami";
    } else {
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";
    }

    if (radMushrooms.isSelected()) {
        p += 0.50;
        order += "Mushrooms";
    }else{
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";
    }
    if (radOlives.isSelected()) {
        p += 0.50;
        order += "Olives";
    }else{
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";
    }
    if (radCapsicum.isSelected()) {
        p += 0.50;
        order += "Capsicum";
    }else{
        p += 0.00;
        order += "";

        if (radPineapple.isSelected()) {
            p += 0.50;
            order += "Pineapple";
        }else  {
            p += 0.00;
            order += "";
        }
        if (chkNo.isSelected()) {

            order += "Pick-up";
        }

        if (chkYes.isSelected()) {
            p += 1.00;
            order += "Delivery";
        }

        lblOrder.setText(order);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change all your `if` statements to include braces around the actions you want executed based on the state you are checking.

For example, at the moment, if `chkLarge.isSelected` is `true`, the following code will still make the `order` equal to `Medium`

```
if (chkLarge.isSelected()) 
    p = 8.00;

order = "Large";

if (chkMedium.isSelected()) 
    p = 8.00;

order = "Medium";
```

With out a `{...}` block, only the first line after the statement is executed.  It's always encouraged to use braces, as it gives a clear context to what you are trying to do ... and no, intention makes no difference.

So, instead, the code should look more like....

```
if (chkLarge.isSelected()) {
    p = 8.00;
    order = "Large";
} else if (chkMedium.isSelected()) 
    p = 8.00;
    order = "Medium";
} // Other conditions you need
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer one of my questions, i understand it's getting down voted because it's rather basic. It was a huge help i can't believe i missed that, that's how i had it originally but a lot of youtube videos left that out so i changed it.